# Access Array of objects from different class

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

So here is the problem.
I have one array, there are two classes of object in it.
Email which is the superclass and UniversityEmail which is the inheritance class.
The array is of type Email.
I wanna print out all the object of type Email from the array.
Or print out UniversityEmail object based on a private variable extends by UniversityEmail class.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] instanceof Email) && (!(array[i] instanceof UniversityEmail)) {
    //print your object 
  }  
}
```

That's typed just from mind, so there might be some smaller issues.